# yii2 show hidden field

Tags: javascript, field, yii2

I have problem to show the hidden field. this is my script :

```
<script>
function showOther(obj){
    if(obj=="Lainnya"){
        document.getElementById('user-bank_other').style.display="block"; 
        return false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('user-bank_other').style.display="none"; 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then this is my form :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'bank_id')->dropDownList([ '1' => 'Bank Central Asia', '2' => 'CIMB Niaga', '9999' => 'Lainnya', ], ['prompt' => '-Pilih Bank-'], array('onchange'=>'return showOther(this.value)'))->label('Nama Bank') ?>
```

But didn't work :(. any suggestions?
Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the value that you pass into js function with `showOther(this.value)` is not *Lainnya* its *9999*. If you want to check for exact text and not the integer value try this `return showOther(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML)`

**UPD:**
to get `onchange` attribute, you need to place it into the same array where you place *prompt* option. Inseat of:

```
['prompt' => '-Pilih Bank-'], array('onchange'=>'return showOther(this.value)'))
```

Use:

```
['prompt' => '-Pilih Bank-', 'onchange'=>'return showOther(this.value)']
```

Comment: My bad :). i already changed it, but still not work... did i forget something to use javascript in yii2?

Comment: @MuhammadMaulana is there any js errors in a console ? also try console.log(obj) in `showOther` function at very beginning

Comment: No, there is no error.. i confused, when i inspected element, there is no 'onchange' attribut : 
<select name="User[bank_id]" class="form-control" id="user-bank_id">
<option value="">-Pilih Bank-</option>
<option value="1">Bank Central Asia</option>
<option value="2">CIMB Niaga</option>
<option value="9999">Lainnya</option>
</select>

Comment: Many thank to you @Tony. Thank you very much, its work :).
I modify my java script function : 

document.getElementById('user-bank_other').setAttribute('type', 'text');

SOLVED...